# Qual a diferença entre essas opções de criação de Form Delphi?

Tags: delphi, formulário

Temos as seguintes opções:

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form);
```

e

```
Form := TForm.Create(Application);
```

Existe diferença entre as duas?

Sei que existe porque dependendo de onde chamamos cada uma delas a variavel “Form” não estará disponivel para outros formularios

Qual exatamente a diferença se Application é proprietaria?

Comment: Pelo que sei não existe diferença, é simplesmente métodos de construção diferente. Sobre `não estará disponível para outros formulários` pode explicar melhor essa parte?

Comment: Mesmo após pesquisas e colocar a pergunta aqui insisti na resposta e realmente tem diferença, Application.CreateForm Cria uma variável global desta forma o formulário é visto em qualquer parte da aplicação, já o TForm.Create cria uma variável dentro do formulário onde foi instanciada não estando portanto disponível em outras instancias gerando a falsa impressão de que esta disponível em outro formulário, eu vou responder essa pergunta e tentar detalhar como funciona.

Comment: Lendo sua resposta entendi sua pergunta, a parte na pergunta: `não estará disponível para outros formulários` não ficou tão clara! Faz uma edição na pergunta e melhora essa parte onde esta a duvida. +1 pela Resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Colocando a diferença entre os métodos de construção de Formulários no Delphi

```
1 - Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form);
```

Cria uma variável de escopo global podendo ser instanciada em qualquer outro Formulário, claro com a prévia adição da Unit no Formulário em que se deseja usa-la, exemplo a grosso modo:

```
Application.CreateForm(TFormCliente, FormCliente);
  Application.CreateForm(TFormDetalhes, FormDetalhes);
    Application.CreateForm(TFormSubDetalhes, FormSubDetalhes);
    FormDetalhes.SubShowModal;

       ... rotina ...
       Aqui estará disponpivel o formulário FormCliente e FormDetalhes
       ... Aguarda FormSubDetalhes ser fechado para continuar

  FormDetalhes.ShowModal;

    Idem

FormCliente.ShowModal;
```

Neste caso o formulário FormCliente estaria disponivel nos outros dois criados posteriormente ( desde que adicionada a unit FormCliente em USES )

2 - Form := TForm.Create(Application);

Mesmo dizendo que o dono é Application ele não estará disponível em uma chamada de um formulário ShowModal posterior a ele, exemplo a grosso modo:

```
FormCliente := TFormCliente.Create(Application);
  FormDetalhes := TFormDetalhes.Create(Application);
    FormSubDetalhes := TFormSubDetalhes.Create(Application);
    FormDetalhes.SubShowModal;

       ... rotina ...
       Aqui não estará disponpivel o formulário FormCliente nem FormDetalhes
       ... Aguarda FormSubDetalhes ser fechado para continuar

  FormDetalhes.ShowModal;

    Idem

FormCliente.ShowModal;
```

Form := TForm.Create(Application); Cria uma variável local, por isso ao tentar usar o formulário em outras units dará o erro AccessViolation, pois o formulário (variável) não foi criado globalmente

Uma outra forma de entender:

Dentro de uma função podemos criar variáveis que serão de uso exclusivo daquela função, exemplo 1

```
function fTeste(): Integer;
var vlocal: Integer;
begin
  result := vlocal+1;
end;
```

Se tentar usar a variável vlocal fora da função terá um erro, pois a variável não foi criada globalmente.

Exemplo 2:

```
public // Declarando a variável para ser publica (global)
  vpublica: Integer;

function fTeste(): Integer;
begin
  result := vpublica+1;
end;
```

No exemplo 2 a variável vpublica estará disponível em qualquer parte do formulário atual e de qualquer formulário que deseje usar essa unit

Resumo descritivo:

Eu confundia a criação do Formulário com a criação da Variável Form, explico, quando se está criando o formulário podemos dizer quem é o dono do formulário, se a aplicação ou outros, isso é preciso saber para o momento de destruição da aplicação, para a liberação correta da memória, já a criação da variável se será global ou local, lhe dará poder para usa-la localmente ou globalmente, eu achava que quando colocássemos "Application" o formulário criado estaria disponível em toda e qualquer parte da aplicação.

Espero ter sido claro.

Comment: O Owner do form e a sua visibilidade sao coisas completamente diferentes... acho que está a misturar.

Se eu tiver no arranque da app
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
  Form5:=TForm5.Create(application);

Tanto o form3 como o form5 sao publicos e acessiveis de qualquer lado. posso chamar o form5 no form3 à vontade...

Comment: O exemplo aqui são para forms criados em tempo de execução.

Comment: Então Tiago, se eu criar os formularios lá no arranque da aplicação concordo contigo, serão variaveis globais, não importa como crie, mas meu exemplo mostra a criação em tempo de execução depois da chamada de uma tela por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença é que com Application.CreateForm o formulário criado será o "MainForm" (formulário principal) se ainda não estiver definido. Não há outras diferenças com relação à visibilidade ou utilização do formulário.

Comment: Então Ricardo, não sei se não estou compreendendo bem o caso da criação, mas na pratica usando ShowModal, não funciona assim, se criar um formulario antes com Form := TForm.Create não tera a variavel Form disponivel dentro do Form Modal criado depois, então pelo menos na pratica faz diferença, como expliquei eu confundia o dono do formulario com a variavel que recebe o objeto form.

Comment: Marcelo, é apenas uma questão de declarar uma variável com o escopo adequado. Se houver uma variável visível não haverá diferença no ShowModal.

Comment: Se você colocar a unit do form na cláusula uses e a variável estiver declarada na sessão interface (do mesmo form), será visível globalmente.

Comment: Eu gostaria de ter um exemplo funcional dessa questão, pois sei que muitos, mas muitos programadores apanham nessa questão, a principio não vejo diferença entre criar Application.Create e Form := TForm.Create, acontece que há uma diferença concreta, pois mesmo fazendo as devidas referencias nas Units o formulario criado com a segunda opção pode não estar disponivel no Form Modal aberto, não sei se o Stack permite link pra download, eu poderia fazer um exemplo simples e colocar a disposição para explicar melhor o que estou dizendo.

Comment: Se você disponibilizar o link eu farei o download para podermos  analisar melhor.

Comment: Segue o link pra vocês verem o que quero dizer...  
http://mvsoftware.com.br/downloads/TesteFormCreate.rar

Comment: Marcelo, no seu exemplo, o FDetalhes cria o FSubDetalhes no construtor. Assim, quando o FDetalhes é criado com: "FDetalhes := TFDetalhes.Create(Application);", seu construtor está sendo invocado antes do endereço do objeto criado ser atribuído à variável FDetalhes. Por isso FSubDetalhes não consegue acessar FDetalhes "ainda". Normalmente, tentamos encapsular os forms para que não sejam tão dependentes entre si. Se o acesso de FSubDetalhes a FDetalhes for feito após o término da atribuição, a variável estará visível independentemente do método utilizado para chamar o construtor.

Comment: Sim Ricardo, percebi isso, mas note que na primeira forma ele é criado completamente antes de qualquer execução e não gera erro, então existe uma diferença entres os métodos de criação, estou tentando entender as diferenças para que use cada método de criação no seu devido lugar para acabar com os erros de memoria nas minhas aplicações, estava fazendo um teste com Splash e percebi que não posso usar Application.CreateForm no inicio, pois quando fecho o Form Splash ele fecha a aplicação, já com o TForm.Create isso não acontece.

Comment: Sim, quando o MainForm é fechado a aplicação encerra. Esse é o principal atributo do MainForm e o principal efeito do Application.CreateForm. Observe que este método faz toda uma ginástica para atribuir o endereço do objeto à var Reference e, depois, acaba por executar o Create.

Comment: Entendo que quando o MainForm fecha quer dizer que a aplicação se foi, porém existe a possibilidade de exibirmos um Splash com status até que o MainForm e afins estejam completamente carregados e então depois fechar o Splash e mostrar o MainForm, pelo que fiz aqui essa rotina acontece no Applicaton.Run, seria no começo do começo... então eu preciso criar o Splash antes do MainForm... se eu criar com Create(nil) ele funciona, se criar com Application.CreateForm não funciona, me parece que neste ponto tenho que dizer que ninguém é dono do Form Splash, quero essas ideias clareadas.

Comment: Está correto. Poderia usar TSplashForm.Create(Application), mas não há a menor necessidade.